# Orientation based on mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, mesh, gameobject

I need to find the orientation of the plane(mesh) created on 4 points(vector3) (2 triangles).

And I want to rotate another game object to match rotation from this plane.

google don't help

I want to set orientation of other game object to rotation from mesh. Best if mesh plane fit X and Y axis of setted gameObject

Comment: Check out this answer [Calculate Normal and Plane Orientation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/202242/calculate-normal-and-plane-orientation-using-4-3d-points) from the gamedev stackexchange site.

Comment: Thanks i will check it later today, but looks promisng.